# How can I pipe a file without having buffer build up in Node.JS?

Tags: node.js

I'm using Node.JS to proxy a file upload to a remote endpoint and need to make sure my Node server doesn't buffer the file excessively.

I'm using `res.write` to push in the following way:

```
apiRes.on('data', function (chunk) {
    body += chunk;
    res.write(chunk);
});
```

(The connection is faster from client to node than from node to the remote).

Note that the client is a browser, if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Node.js API Docs](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipe_destination_options)

```
apiRes.pipe(res);
```

Comment: This the perfect solution if the POST data from the browser has only file data. But if you are using a form to do this, the data will have multipart markers, which is not what you would expect.

Answer (score 2):

- use xhr.send file with the help of [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/FileReader).
- use apiRes.pipe(res) as suggested by Dream707